# Advice loading resources within a visual c# project

Tags: c#, loading, embedded-resource

I have been asked to create a project which involves loading profiles into a UI in which the user can edit the values. I need to be able to load data from a file within the project and allow the user to make chnages and save back to that file.

All of this has to be contained within an executable but I am unsure of the best way to approach this, I was think of using an XML file with an XML structure or a text file and just string split on it or even a resources file and just call out to it.

I thought I would put my problem up on here and see what the community suggest, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedded resources are not intended to be changed during runtime.  A database is really easy to auto-create these days using code-first EF, but a file containing XML or JSON would also be a good option (as there are third-party libraries to help you parse the result).  Hand-rolling your own string.split solution is not recommended (because if requirements get more complex in the future, your code may become unmanageable)

Comment: I use EF in my main projects at work so it wouldn't be an issue to create. The thing I'm wanting is a standalone EXE with no outside dependencies, is it possible to roll up a DB within the EXE?

Comment: I believe it's possible to move and then replace a windows EXE while it's running, but that way lies madness.  If you can't have a config/settings file, what about storing the settings in the registry?

Comment: It doesn't have to be anything overly complex, I need the settings to be permanent, so if a change is made, it is recorded and can be taken in further versions. I am probably making this harder than it should be, the application uses very specific equations and I know the equation will not change but the values used may. I just need a way to keep a record of the data.

Comment: User-editable settings are never EVER stored in exe files.  As I said there's the Windows Registry and there's a settings file.  If for some reason neither of those seems right, I suggest taking a hard look at your actual requirements and and explaining them in another question.

Comment: I think you're right, I could do with re-examining my approach to this